# Choose fast/medium/slow track order in Legend?

Tags: legend

I recently discoverend the Legend RPG, and was reading through the PDF, when I found one thing I do not understand: **if I do NOT multiclass, do I get to choose which is my fast/medium/slow track, or does the class fix it for me?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is fixed by the class. It’s a common houserule to allow people to swap them around, but officially you can’t and you have to use them in the progression listed in the class table.

The development team isn’t aware of any particular problems with this houserule, it’s just not something they’re officially supporting.

Comment: In effect, I do not see any major drawback or imbalance in allowing it... or is there?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Having just asked the dev team, the response was “I think we were pretty much fine with it,” so no, there is no (known) major drawback or imbalance in allowing it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's a homebrew that let's you build tracks from scratch (particularly useful if you're a fan of the additional tracks). The upshot is, you could rebuild the official classes with the tracks in different orders and it wouldn't cost you anything.

Comment: @EpsilonRose can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by "build tracks"?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Sorry, that was a typo. It lets you build classes from almost any set of tracks (esoterica radica and one of the paladin tracks are locked).

Comment: Is such homebrew documented anywhere, like another PDF document available for download?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Most homebrew would be found on the [official forums](http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/).